# How to add code tags in aloha editor...?

Tags: javascript, plugins, aloha-editor

I would like to add code tag to my aloha editor. can any one please tell me how to add the **'code'** to aloha editor

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation it should be possible with the format-plugin http://aloha-editor.org/guides/plugin_format.html, but activating "code" in the settings does not work. Looking at the current sources the support for the "code"-element seems to be missing or still a todo. (https://github.com/alohaeditor/Aloha-Editor/blob/alohaeditor-0.25.4/src/plugins/common/format/lib/format-plugin.js)

Either you write your own Aloha-Plugin for this functionality (http://aloha-editor.org/guides/writing_plugins.html) or you can open an issue on the Aloha-Editor Github page (https://github.com/alohaeditor/Aloha-Editor/issues) and wait until it is fixed.